# substr in Oracle from column

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

What is the Syntax to substr in Oracle to subtract a string 
i have "123456789     #073"
I only want what after the #

substr (table.col, 17,3)
is that ok ?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the simplest (and most performant) way of doing this would be to use the base string functions:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, '#') + 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

We could also try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '.*#(.*)', '\1')
FROM yourTable;
```

The regex option would in general not perform as well as the first query.  The reason for this is that invoking a regex incurs a performance overhead.  You might want to consider a regex option if you expect that the string logic might change or get more complicated in the future.  Otherwise, go with base string functions wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most direct method might be `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr('123456789 #073', '[^#]+$')
from dual;
```

The regular expression says:  "get me all non-hash characters at the end of the string".

If you happen to know that there are 3 characters and really want the last three characters of the string:

```
select substr('123456789 #073', -3)
```